# How to group list of data based on one field

Tags: java, algorithm, stream, java-stream

I have a list of custom class data, I want to group them based on one field and the value should be another field. Take the example below.

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Student(1001, "Class 1", "Jon"));
list.add(new Student(1002, "Class 1", "Eliana"));
list.add(new Student(1003, "Class 2", "Piter"));
list.add(new Student(1004, "Class 3", "Joy"));
list.add(new Student(1005, "Class 2", "Anderson"));
list.add(new Student(1006, "Class 1", "Ram"));
list.add(new Student(1007, "Class 1", "Mohan"));
```

Now I would like to group this data based on class. The expected output should be a map containing key as the class and value as the list of student names.

```
{"Class 1" -> ["Jon", "Eliana", "Ram", "Mohan"]}
{"Class 2" -> ["Piter", "Anderson"]}
{"Class 3" -> ["Joy"]}
```

I want to get this using java 8 stream feature. I tried doing this and I could group the whole object into a map as the key being the class name and value is a list of students. But my requirement is to get value as the only a list of student names.

My pice of code is something like this:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Students::getClass));
```

Comment: You can use`mapping` collectors: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Students::getClass,Collectors.mapping(Student:getName,toList())));`

Comment: thanks dude, it seems to be working

Comment: You can add it as an answer so that others can get it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comments section, it can be done in this way:

```
Map<EligibilityRequest, List<List<String>>> result = 
  list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getClass,
      Collectors.mapping(Student::getName,  toList())
    ));
```